# Generate several rows with test data for item

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this SQL query to generate test data for table `onboarding_tasks`:

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks (business_name, meta_title, status, task_type)
SELECT
    'Business name ' || id AS business_name,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    (ARRAY['NEW','IN_PROGRESS','COMPLETED'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS status,
    (ARRAY['CHECK', 'TEST'])[floor(random()*3)+1] AS task_type
FROM generate_series(1,25) as g(id);
```

In the second query I generate test data using `id` from first table `onboarding_tasks`:

```
INSERT into onboarding_task_item (title, task_id, onboarding_tasks)
SELECT
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    ot.id,
    generate_series(1,50) AS onboarding_tasks
FROM onboarding_tasks ot;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ad1ff5751766dd02c15270191fa7956)

Right now I generate only 1 row in table `onboarding_task_item`. How I can generate 4 table rows with test data per one row from `onboarding_tasks`?

Comment: Just to be sure before posting an answer, you mean this? `SELECT
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    ot.id,
    generate_series(1,5) AS onboarding_tasks
FROM onboarding_tasks ot
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,4)
ORDER BY id,onboarding_tasks;`

Comment: Do you want to generate the 4 rows with the same data ? If not, what is the expected content for each row ?

Comment: @JimJones yes, correct

Comment: @EdouardH. yes, I need different random data.

Comment: @PeterPenzov so my answer might interest you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `CROSS JOIN` the result set with a `geneate_series()` call, which means that all records of the result set will be joined with all records from `generate_series()`, e.g.

```
SELECT     
  left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,     
  ot.id,       
  generate_series(1,5) AS onboarding_tasks 
FROM onboarding_tasks ot 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,4);
```

Or perhaps like this if you need the generated value:

```
SELECT
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    ot.id,
    j.id AS gen_id
FROM onboarding_tasks ot
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,4) j(id);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2894cbcbef46919d0dfeb2ad9a2d019d)